# ARM function start points look strange sometimes in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, arm

I am a little bit confused with this strange issue with ARM firmware. My original firmware file has no symbols, so I need to find them by myself trough the internet. But here I have a certain function of which I am sure. I have some reliable xrefs to it. But sometimes, some function call the loc_'s following its start. Look here:

[image]

So, it should start from the STMFD as usual, but here is not the case. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you see nonsensical ARM instructions with conditional suffixes it's likely data being disassembled. Double-check your firmware load address and inspect the calling code; I think the call may have been bogus code too, which caused IDA to start disassembling at a wrong place.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Now I see that this firmware contains some separate modules that cause this conflict.